# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not set unknown property 'useIR' for object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptionsImpl

Tags: java, android, kotlin, github, build.gradle

i cloned kickstarter from github & facing this error

```
 kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    useIR = true
}
```

i have tried rebuilding , cleaning project but cant resolve this issue
& there are no similar issues i found out there

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

> Could not set unknown property 'useIR' for object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOption

```
    // Copy google-services.json from variant directory to root of app

gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
    if (task.name ==~ /process.*GoogleServices/) {
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (task.name ==~ /(?i)process${variant.name}GoogleServices/) {
                copy {
                    from "src/${variant.name}"
                    into '.'
                    include 'google-services.json'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am not sure if this might help but this error cannot reslove 'task' is in build gradle & this is the only error

Answer (score 16):

Remove the

> UseIR = true

option and your code should compile

Answer (score 12):

Which kotlin version you are using? It seems to be removed in 1.7.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compatibility-guide-17.html#remove-useir-compiler-option.
[image]